# Keyboard wrong characters output, ssh works well

Tags: ssh, keyboard

I have problem, when I connect into raspberry pi B+ keyboard its outputing wrong characters. ex. When I trigger S it return O. If I connect with SSH to this RPi it works normal, keyboard language is CZ

Comment: What os are you running? What locale is the os set in? Do you have a `/etc/default/keyboard`-file, and if so, what does it say? Did you research `man keyboard`?

Comment: raspbian latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reconfigure you keyboard settings.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Follow the prompts. Then restart your RasPi.

```
reboot
```

Or:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

look for

```
XKBLAYOUT=
```

and place "cz" there.